# Switchmap() function not working with multiple events

Tags: rxjs

I have tried an approach to merge multiple events but I couldn't get it to work - basically this line works just fine for a single event.

```
Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'mousemove')
.switchMap(() =>  Observable.timer(0, 1000))
```

I would like to do the same thing for multiple events like `mousemove` and `keyup` so I did this:

```
let mergedEvents = Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'mousemove')
                  .merge(Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'keyup'))
mergedEvents.subscribe(event => event.switchMap(() =>  Observable.timer(0, 1000))
```

which is not working - how can i get this to work with multiple events?

Comment: `mergedEvents.switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 1000)).subscribe(/*...*/)`

Comment: @cartant, Sorry that is not working, error `subscription is not assignable to type Observable<number>`

Comment: What is not working? What's the expected behaviour? What's the current behaviour? Is it an exception? Are you getting more events than expected? Less events than expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cann't chain the switchMap with your mergedEvens:

```
let mergedEvents = Observable
  .fromEvent(document.body, 'mousemove')
  .merge(Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'keyup'))

mergedEvents
  .switchMap(() => Observable.timer(0, 1000))
  .(...)
```

Example here: https://jsbin.com/xiyuvuwogo/1/edit?js,console,output (here I use the click into document, to check it just click into output)